# Get message content from mime message?

Tags: spring, email, spring-integration

I have a java spring integration project that is receving emails through the below code:

```
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ac =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/integration/gmail-imap-idle-config.xml");
   DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);

            inputChannel.subscribe(message -> {
                org.springframework.messaging.Message<MimeMailMessage> received =
                    (org.springframework.messaging.Message<MimeMailMessage>) message;

                log.info("content" + message);

                List<String> sentences = null;
                try {


            } catch (Exception e) {

                }
```

I get the email, and I can get the subject, but I can never actually extract the message body.  How do I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use this option on the channel adapter:

```
simple-content="true"
```

See its description:

> When 'true', messages produced by the source will be rendered by 'MimeMessage.getContent()'
>                       which is usually just the body for a simple text email. When false (default) the content
>                       is rendered by the 'getContent()' method on the actual message returned by the underlying
>                       javamail implementation.
>                       For example, an IMAP message is rendered with some message headers.
>                       This attribute is provided so that users can enable the previous behavior, which just
>                       rendered the body.

But still it is doubtful, since I see in case of GMail message it is never simple. The content is a `MimeMultipart` and we need to read its parts to get access to the real body.

So, this is how you should change your code as well:

```
log.info("content" + ((MimeMultipart) ((MimeMessage) message.getPayload()).getContent()).getBodyPart(0).getContent());
```